# Contribute to Roth IRA for year 2021 without ITIN or SSN. (ITIN applied)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira, itin

**Context:** I came to the USA via F2 (student visa) in September 2021 after getting married. My husband’s status is resident alien and he has an SSN. Additionally, he was on an F1 visa for the entire 2021. We have filed a joint income tax return for the first time in 2021. With the tax return, we have applied for my ITIN as well. It is expected to come only after 18th April 2022 (deadline for contributing for 2021 ROTH).

**Questions:**

1. I want to contribute to my Roth IRA for the year 2021. Is there any way I can do that without having my ITIN before 18th April 2022?
2. Can I contribute to my account for 2021 after 18th April 2022?

Please feel free to ask if the situation is not clear.

Comment: @Chor Siphai, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to contribute to my Roth IRA for the year 2021. Is there any way I can do that without having my ITIN before 18th April 2022?

I don't believe having ITIN or SSN is a legal requirement for eligibility for IRA, but it may be a technical requirement to actually open an account.

In addition, you can only contribute to IRA up to **earned** income you have during the year, and for married couples one spouse can use the income earned by the other for that calculation (See [Pub. 550-A](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a#en_US_2021_publink1000230412)).

Also, it is not at all certain that your spouse who's on F1 visa is in fact a resident alien for 2021. I don't know if you've actually confirmed that or making an assumption.

> Can I contribute to my account for 2021 after 18th April 2022?

No.

Comment: For the second question: There may be one option, backdoor IRA. I am not aware of all the details but have heard of it several times. You may find more about it.

Comment: @PHcoDer no, "backdoor" IRA is still time-limited and you must initiate the first step before the return due date (April 18th)

Comment: The model agreements for Roth IRA (5305R and 5305RA) do not ask for TIN, and while the trustee/custodian requests TIN for 5498 reporting,  the instructions on (official/non-substitute) W-9, after explaining TIN is either SSN or ITIN, say "If you are asked to complete Form W-9 but do not have a TIN, apply for a TIN and **write 'Applied For' in the space for the TIN** ...." Also a nit: for married couples _filing jointly_ (as in this Q) one spouse can contribute based on other's (taxable) compensation.